# 401 Unauthorized - IIS website to SSRS 2017 report/folder

Tags: kerberos, spn, ssrs-2017

I have an IIS website running with its apppool running under LocalSystem connecting to an SSRS 2017 site that's running under NetworkService.  SSRS reports with domain user access  load fine in the website's reportviewer page, but reports with specific AD group/user access throw 401 unauthorized in the reportviewer page.  My AD account gets the error from the site, but I can browse directly to the Reports path report and it runs fine.

Seems to be a kerberos double hop issue, but I can't figure out where the spns may be failing.  We have http spns for the host name and each alias of the iis site and the computer name (since the site is using LocalSystem and not an AD service account), http spns for the host/aliases of the SSRS site and computer name  (ssrs is using networkservice, not an AD service account) and mssqlsvc(1433) spns for the host/aliases of the sql server that the SSRS server's ReportServer database is on.

I'm not finding anything helpful in the ISS or SSRS logs which is odd, because I've seen 401 show up in the SSRs logs on other servers.  Any ideas?  Thanks!